# Proving Convergence using Taylor Series

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, proof-explanation, taylor-expansion

I was reading the following Wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scoring_algorithm under the "Sketch of Derivation" section:

Let $Y_1,\ldots,Y_n$ be random variables, independent and identically distributed with twice differentiable p.d.f. $f(y; \theta)$, and we wish to calculate the maximum likelihood estimator (M.L.E.) $\theta^*$ of $\theta$.  First, suppose we have a starting point for our algorithm $\theta_0$, and consider a Taylor expansion of the score function, $V(\theta)$, about $\theta_0$:

$$V(\theta) \approx V(\theta_0) - \mathcal{J}(\theta_0)(\theta - \theta_0)$$

where

$$\mathcal{J}(\theta_0) = -\sum_{i=1}^n \left. \nabla \nabla^\top \right|_{\theta=\theta_0} \log f(Y_i; \theta)$$

is the observed information matrix at $\theta_0$.

Now, setting $\theta$ = $\theta*$ , using that $V(\theta^*) = 0$ and rearranging gives us:

$$\theta^* \approx \theta_{0} + \mathcal{J}^{-1}(\theta_{0})V(\theta_{0}).$$

We therefore use the algorithm

$$\theta_{m+1} = \theta_{m} + \mathcal{J}^{-1}(\theta_{m})V(\theta_{m})$$

**and under certain regularity conditions, it can be shown that** $\theta_m \rightarrow \theta^*$.

**My Question:** I am trying to learn about the "regularity conditions" as well as the general proof required to prove the following statement:

**And under certain regularity conditions, it can be shown that** $\theta_m \rightarrow \theta*$.

I tried consulting different sources but I could not understand/find more information about these regularity conditions and a general mathematical proof that shows this convergence property.

Can someone please help me understand this?

Thanks!

- Note: I understand that $\theta* \rightarrow \theta$ , i.e. the classical consistency property of MLE - the MLE estimator converges to the true value as the sample size approaches infinity ....but I am trying to understand why $\theta_m$ (a numerical approximation of  $\theta*$) approaches $\theta_*$ as the number of iterations $m$ becomes large.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern behind that is Newton's method (for optimization). You start with
$$
\phi(\theta)=\sum_{i=1}^n\ln f(Y_i;\theta)\approx \phi(\theta_0)+\phi'(\theta_0)(\theta-\theta_0)+\frac12\phi''(\theta_0)[\theta-\theta_0,\theta-\theta_0]+O(\|\theta-\theta_0\|^3)
$$
Being able to write a big O there is already one regularity condition.

At an extremum of $\phi$ its derivative or gradient is zero
$$
0=V(\theta_*)=\nabla\phi(\theta_*)=\phi'(\theta_*)^\top,\\
V(\theta)=V(\theta_0)+V'(\theta_0)(\theta-\theta_0)+O(\|\theta-\theta_0\|^2)
$$
To extract the derivative of $V$, the Hessian matrix $J=-V'$ of $\phi$, from the bilinear form of the second derivative of $\phi$ requires some linear algebra bricolage, transposition in one argument. Among other things one would have to recall what $\nabla$ stands for. Usually it is the gradient operator, $\nabla \phi(\theta)=\phi'(\theta)^\top$. This seems also to be the case here, so that $\nabla\nabla^\top$ stands for the matrix of all (mixed) second derivative operators.

Thus solving
$$
0=V(\theta_0)-J(\theta_0)(\theta-\theta_0)
$$
is the same as solving
$$
0=V(\theta_0)+V'(\theta_0)(\theta-\theta_0),
$$
which defines the Newton step. One level back it is the same as finding the extremal point of the quadratic function
$$
\phi(\theta_0)+\phi'(\theta_0)(\theta-\theta_0)+\frac12\phi''(\theta_0))[θ−θ_0,θ−θ_0]
$$
Thus you get also the convergence conditions of Newton's method as part of the regularity conditions. These may be expressed in $\phi$ or $f$, and thus perhaps simplify somewhat.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! But is your answer showing that the estimate produced by the iterative numerical algorithm converges to the actual MLE solution? Can you please help me understand this? Thank you so much!

Comment: You get all the pitfalls of the Newton method. You get quadratic convergence if you start close enough to the root, see for instance the Newton-Kantorovich theorem about what close enough is. Otherwise you can get large jumps in the iteration that might infinitely continue, or lead to a non-maximal solution or even stall out far away from any solution. Doing line search along the Newton direction might help in the initial steps.